# Multi-level timeseries forecasting? How to do it?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, python-3.x

So, I just finished a 48 hr datathon, and I did terribly, to be honest. It was my first datathon.

We were given a list of datasets:

- 5 months of taxi demand data (January to May)
- Weather dataset
- Zone neighbors
- dt (date and time of prediction)

And we were told to build a time series forecasting model to forecast the taxi demand. We were told to do it in a forecasting manner, like, **Train with January and Test with February, Train with February and Test with March, and so on.** In the end, they would evaluate our model by testing it with data from June, which we were not given. I just couldn't figure out how to do it.

This is how I wanted to do it : [code snippet link: https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanholbrook/hybrid-models]

```
# 1. Train and predict with first model
model_1.fit(X_train_1, y_train)
y_pred_1 = model_1.predict(X_train)

# 2. Train and predict with second model on residuals
model_2.fit(X_train_2, y_train - y_pred_1)
y_pred_2 = model_2.predict(X_train_2)

# 3. Add to get overall predictions
y_pred = y_pred_1 + y_pred_2
```

Except I'd have to do it 4 times. Because I got 5 datasets.

And we were given this function to evaluate our model before submitting:

```
def predict(self, demand, weather, dt, neighbors):
```

But I just couldn't figure out how to implement this.

My question is, how should I have solved this problem? Using what algorithms?

If you could refer me to an example code or something that'd really help. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a [custom scikit-learn estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html) that combines a regression model with a decision tree and then use the [`TimeSeriesSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) class to split the dataset taking time into account to fit/test your model.

Comment: @Oxbowerce thank you for your reply, I really don't know anything about what you mentioned. I guess I should study it so I understand it.